# Border line works only in Chrome

Tags: css, border

I was developing a website on Chrome and after checking it in Mozilla I was surprised, because border lines for an `<a>` element don't work. The same problem is in IE. What can be the issue here?

HTML:

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 40, 'post_parent' => $this_page_id, 'post_type' => 'page', 'order' => 'ASC')); while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-sm-4 grid"> 
        <a class="grid-item" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' ); ?> );">
                <div class="center">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>                              
        </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a.grid-item {border-right:1px solid #eee;border-top:1px solid #eee;}
.grid:nth-child(3n+1) a.grid-item{border-left:1px solid #eee;}
```

Comment: There are issues for mozilla with borders. As per my knowledge, the solution might be by adding images as borders in place. But still researching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery("a.grid-item").css({"border-right":"1px solid #eee","border-top":"1px solid #eee"});
```

Answer (score 0):

display:table affect the borders so add border to parent.

Add below css to your code

```
.grid:nth-child(3n+1) {
   border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.grid {
   border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
 }
```

Remove below css to your code

```
.grid:nth-child(3n+1) a.grid-item {
   border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
a.grid-item {
   border-right: 1px solid #eee;
   border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: @Dandy now check it. If any doubt let me know.